# Unsubscribe link broken in Developer Story E-Mail

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, email

I just got an email about something I didn't even know existed - Developer Story and the discontinuation thereof. No biggie, there's an unsubscribe link at the bottom. But that leads to a 404 (not even handled by SO's servers, just the Void).

A second link allowed me to edit my email preferences, and that did lead to the SO server, except that it still 404-ed on the backend.

C'mon Stack, check the links and allow me to unsub from these mails.

Comment: @BDL The links contain a bunch of BASE64 mess, and I'm not sure if it has personal information, so no, I'd prefer not.

Comment: This is the link I got today: https://stackoverflow.email/subscriptions/unsubscribe-bucket/

Comment: I also received the mail now and can confirm that the link is broken.

Comment: Seems the real bug here is that it shouldn't have included an unsubscribe link at all. It 404s because it's missing information about which email bucket. These are being sent through the legal bucket as transactional emails, which cannot be unsubscribed, and thus there is no unsubscribe link for them. Similarly, the "You're receiving this email because you have a Developer Story on Stack Overflow." line at the bottom is broken in the latest email as well.

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for the inconveniences in the Developer Story email that went out, we had some similar issues with our "The Overflow" digest, and those have been fixed.

Unfortunately the Developer Story email was a one-off (since we were announcing it's end), so we can't go back in time to fix that one (it would be cool if we could though! We need a Time Manipulation R&D team here at Stack).

I'll mark this one as completed for now, please create a new post if by any chances you get another email with broken links.

Thank you for reporting, and again sorry about the annoyance.